# How to show f is Riemann integrable over R?

Tags: real-analysis

If $R= [0,2] \times [0,2]$
$$ f(x_1,x_2) = \begin{cases}
0 &&\text{if}\ x_1 \leq 1\\
1 &&\text{if}\ x_1>1 \text{ and } x_2 \leq 1 \\
2 &&\text{if}\ x_1>1 \text{ and } x_2 > 1 \end{cases}$$

Comment: Maybe you can find an appropriate partition for which the upper and lower sum is the same?

Comment: $[0,2]\times[0,2]$ is compact and $f$ is nonnegative and bounded, hence $f$ is (Lebesgue) integrable.

Comment: In the future I would avoid using $R$ to denote a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, to avoid possible confusion between $R$ and $\mathbb R$.